# htaccess - run .htaccess file content in php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to run, convert or interpret the `regular expressions` and `rewrite rules` from `.htaccess` file in `php` to get the outputted url for debugging and optimization purpose?

Comment: What you want to do?? Router can solve your requirements if using reliable Frameworks..

Comment: A router is what I am trying to implement. I was thinking about running the same htaccess file from a router application to get the headers and url and proceed with the maine application. but  before that I just want to be shure no easier interaction between htaccess and php already exists

Comment: You should look HttpFoundation module of Symfony 2 framework. I think it is ready to use Router solution , try this.

Comment: Thanks. I have just bookmarked this https://github.com/symfony/Routing